# How to write ii chord in minor (SATB)

Tags: satb

In TCL grade 6 theory, Roman numerals should not contain diminished or augmented symbols like iio, III+, etc. Then how to perceive "ii" in minor scale. Because in A minor, B diminished which is "ii" in natural minor/harmonic minor and B minor which is also "ii" in melodic minor with raised 6th in ascending.

So if asked ii in A minor in SATB chords, whether I have to write B minor or B diminished?

Comment: For those who had to look it up like me, TCL stands for Trinity College London (I normally see mentions of Trinity a lot more often here than mentions of TCL).

Comment: @Dekkadeci I know; I went looking last time and concluded "not the Chinese electronics company..."

Comment: I assume that if there are rules, they're stated somewhere. I also assume that, if they don't want symbols, then they either want the chord quality indicated in writing, whether fully spelled out ("diminished," "augmented") or abbreviated as "dim."/"aug." But I would also assume that a test would specify natural/melodic/harmonic minor and not leave you to wonder.

Answer (score 1):

Were I the candidate, I'd be writing both - in longhand. With an explanation about differing minors. Best people to ask would, of course, be TCL themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask Trinity College about your assignments.

Aside from that you should be aware that:

- Roman numeral analysis (RNA) exists in several systems and not all use marks like `o` or `+`, or upper/lower case to indicate chord quality. The most basic RNA is Roman numerals (usually upper case) that denote *only* the scale degree of the chord root.
- Regardless of how you might label a chord, the *diatonic* chord on the second scale degree in minor keys is a diminished triad. Some RNA systems will label it `II`, other systems will label it `iio`.
- The chord on the second degree could take another quality. For example if could be a major chord, like `V/V`, which would be a major chord.

> So if asked ii in A minor in SATB chords, whether I have to write B minor or B diminished?

Check with your teacher. I would *expect*, without more context, the question meant *which diatonic triad* for `ii`? and they are using a key signature of no sharps/flats for `A` minor. In which case the chord is `B` diminished.

The important thing is that you can *explain* why you would answer one way or the other, or why the question - at least as you have worded it - it unclear.